# Finding b (knowing that b>=0) in which Pr(2-b < Z < 2+b) = 0.4 and Z~Normal(0,1).

Tags: probability

Is it possible to find the value of b (without using a numerical method -  this observation weren't in the first version of the question) in which 
Pr(2-b < Z < 2+b) = 0.4
where b is a nonnegative value (b >= 0) and Z is a continuous random variable following a standard normal distribution?

Would be nice find b in function of something like the inverse of the CDF of Z...

Thanks in advance, 
Felipe

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done numerically; Note that $P(2 - b < Z < 2 + b) = \Phi(2 + b) - \Phi(2 - b)$. Now any algorithm to solve equations approximately [e.g. Newton method] will yield a value of $b \approx  1.74688$ [see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201%2F2*%28erf%28%282%2Bx%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%20-%20erf%28%282-x%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%29%20%3D%200.4)].

However, I doubt that this equation can be solved exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also would like to know if there is a way to solve without using a numerical method.
Do you think the only way of solving this equation is using a numerical method?

Comment: I highly doubt that $b$ can be calculated without using numerical methods [that's what my last sentence in the answer is supposed to mean].

Comment: Could you explain why you highly doubt?

Comment: The problem is that the CDF of the standard Gaussian distribution doesn't have any nice properties around the value $2$. There is no symmetry that simplifies the term into a single function that might be invertible. It's mostly experience that tells me there will probably be no solution in terms of standard functions.

Comment: @Dominik don't doubt; feel free to be sure :-)

Comment: As b (b >=0) is a monotonic function of Pr(2-b < Z < 2+b), I was suspecting that could be a chance that the term could be simplified into a single function that might be invertible. But because of the explanation, now I believe that is impossible to find the exact answer. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Dominik, feel free to NOT be sure. Now I have the answer for my original question. I will answer my  original post with a final EXACT equation for b.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my original question is given below.

Pr(2-b < Z < 2+b) = 0.4

Pr(-b < Z-2 < b) = 0.4

Pr((Z-2)^2 < b^2) = 0.4

(Z-2)^2 follows a non-central qui-squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom and non-centrality parameter given by 2^2 = 4. So let's call X = (Z-2)^2, then

Pr(X < b^2) = 0.4

F(b^2) = 0.4

Where F is the c.d.f. of a non-central qui-squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom and non-centrality 4, then

b^2 = invF(0.4)

Where invF(a) is the a-quantile of a non-central qui-squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom and non-centrality 4, then

b = squareroot[invF(0.4)]

invF(0.4) can be easily calculated using any stat software such as R [in R, just use the code qchisq(0.4,1,4)]. this gives invF(0.4) = 3.051606, then

b = squareroot[3.051606]

Taking the square root of 3.051606, finally we have

b = 1.746885

Note that what is very interesting here is the fact the we can write b in function of the CDF of a non-central qui-squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom. The non-centrality parameter will just depend on the value being decreased and summed by b inside the initial probability. In this question this value is 2, so the non-centrality parameter is 4. But this can be any value you want.

The function squareroot[invF(0.4)] is the final EXACT solution for b. Also note the 0.4 can be any value between 0 and 1, not necessarily 0.4.